# How to mount a harddisk in linux not showing as /dev/sdx

Tags: router, external-hard-drive, mount

I'm trying to mount external 2,5" usb harddisk to my router (ASUS WL500gp V2). Because the router doesn't give enough power, I'm using external powered hdd enclosure. Earlier it mounted the hdd automatically, now I can't see the hdd in

```
df
```

and

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/disc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

                                 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/part1               1       44750   359452672  83 Linux
/dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/part2           44750       60802   128932864  83 Linux
```

When I try to mount the scsi directly:

```
[admin@wl /tmp]$ mount /dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/part1 /tmp/harddrive/part1
mount: mounting /dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/part1 on /tmp/harddrive/part1 failed: Invalid argument

[admin@wl /tmp]$ mount /dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/part1 /tmp/harddrive/part1 -v -t ext2
mount: mounting /dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/part1 on /tmp/harddrive/part1 failed: No such device
```

When I connect the harddisk to the computer (using the same external usb enclosure) everything is ok.

Where is the problem? Can it be hardware related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the router wasn't able to read the ext2 filesystem. After changing to ext3 everything is ok.